# What do you call "squeezed" fruit?

Tags: word-request

Let's say I buy some fruit like bananas or something soft and put them in a bag.

By the time I take them out of the bag, they have been spoiled because I pressed my back against the bag when I was travelling.

What would I call the fruit (or the state they are in)?

The closest word I came up with was "squeeze", but it does not apply here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could say *squashed*, *squished*, *mushed*, or *bruised* (such as spots that appear on an apple where it has hit the ground).

Comment: +1 for bruised; I have a feeling that's the word the O.P. might be looking for, particularly if the bananas are imagined to [look like these](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/health_and_science/explainer/2013/01/130125_EXP_DAMAGEDFRUIT.jpg.CROP.rectangle3-large.jpg) (or maybe [this apple](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_n0V4b73GtRs/TUckD0Yl38I/AAAAAAAAEXc/193t_cgJkb8/s1600/IMG_4322.JPG), or [this peach](http://ipt.us.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/peach-bruise.jpg)).

Comment: Also *pulped*, and the resultant mess can be called *pulp*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would have to be extreme crushing to be called *pulped*, I think. The other words don't imply such an extreme.

Comment: Or you can say "smooshed".